# Date format sorting issue

Tags: asp.net, sorting, datetime, formatting, asp.net-2.0

I am using asp.net 2005 on my system and creating a application. I have an issue with date format sorting. I have a table including three fields like "user name, date time, visit page".

My records for this as below

```
user name     date time              visited page
    xyz          4/4/2013 5:30:45 PM     aaa.aspx    
    xyz          4/4/2013 6:35:15 PM     aaa.aspx    
    xyz          4/4/2013 7:55:45 PM     aaa.aspx    
    xyz          4/4/2013 10:05:45 PM     aaa.aspx    
    xyz          4/4/2013 11:06:45 PM     aaa.aspx
```

I want to sorted this without using java script or jquery.
and the output should be

```
user name     date time              visited page    
xyz          4/4/2013 11:06:45 PM     aaa.aspx    
xyz          4/4/2013 10:05:45 PM     aaa.aspx    
xyz          4/4/2013 7:55:45 PM     aaa.aspx    
xyz          4/4/2013 6:35:15 PM     aaa.aspx    
xyz          4/4/2013 5:30:45 PM     aaa.aspx
```

But I got the output like this

```
user name     date time              visited page    
xyz          4/4/2013 7:55:45 PM     aaa.aspx    
xyz          4/4/2013 6:35:15 PM     aaa.aspx    
xyz          4/4/2013 5:30:45 PM     aaa.aspx
xyz          4/4/2013 11:06:45 PM     aaa.aspx    
xyz          4/4/2013 10:05:45 PM     aaa.aspx
```

I tried to sorted this via dataview but its not working properly
 can any one help me out for this issue.

Comment: Where are the values coming from? SQL? If so, sort there instead of on the client.

Comment: I am using .csv file instead of any sql.

Comment: When you say you "have a table"...do you mean you have a table of data in memory or do you mean you have an HTML table?  What asp.net control will/are you using to create the html table?

Comment: @Penfold: I got all data from ".csv" file using oledb connection and stored in datatable and now I want to sort them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many other ways to read a CSV, including just as a raw text file and simple string parsing.  You can use some of the suggestions in the other answers here, or you can just populate the results into a DataTable, or whatever.  Use whatever you are comfortable with.

The important bit that hasn't been mentioned in the other answers is that you need to be explicit about the datetime format that you are reading.  For example, how do I know that `1/2/2013` represents either January 2nd, or February 1st?

Since the file you have is not using an invariant date format (like ISO8601 for example), then you should somewhere be explicitly providing a format, such as:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(YourDateString,
                                  "M/d/yyyy",  // or "d/M/yyyy"
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your CSV as a ODBC source. Then you have to use Schema.ini and set that field as a datetime.  See the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353.aspx

It should explain this. Then once you're done you can do a SQL Query, and do a simple

```
  SELECT * ORDER BY [date time] desc
```

I personally hate using flat text files, if you could use DTS and get it into a relational database of some sort, that'd be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Read your .csv values into an object with a strongly typed DateTime property and then sort.

```
CsvValue[] values = ReadCsvFile().OrderBy(value => value.DateTime);
```

Where CsvValue is

```
public class CsvValue
{
   public string UserName {get; set;}
   public DateTime DateTime {get; set;}
   public string VisitedPage {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: that was the other method I was thinking about before I posted below. I was going to suggest LINQ, but it's .NET 2005, prior to it's introduction...